# Load XML into cursor sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

i know how to load xml data into cursor but want to know is it always mandatory to specify data type with in with block() like

here xml data is loaded in @DetailXml variable

```
Exec sp_xml_preparedocument @XMLFormat OUTPUT, @DetailXml
-- Create Cursor from XML Table

Declare CurDetailRecord
Cursor For
Select productid,unit,rate,qty,amount
From Openxml (@XMLFormat, '/NewDataSet/PurchaseOrderDetail', 2)
With
(
productid Varchar(10),
unit Varchar(50),
rate decimal(18,2),
qty decimal(18,3),
amount decimal(18,2)
)
```

i just want to know is it always mandatory like with block

```
With
(
productid Varchar(10),
unit Varchar(50),
rate decimal(18,2),
qty decimal(18,3),
amount decimal(18,2)
)
```

or we can also work without with block?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?? Why insist on a cursor??

Answer (score 0):

> just want to know is it always
>   mandatory like with block

The `WITH` block is not mandatory. You can get the result back from OPENXML in an "edge table format".

Have a look in the documentation for OPENXML, Example C. Obtaining results in an edge table format

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx